# How to select an operating system to boot without a keyboard?

Tags: imac, dual-boot

I'm in a pretty sticky situation right now...

The USB keyboard that I've always used broke.  I do have the wireless keyboard that came with my iMac.  However, my iMac is dual-booted.  When I turn it on, the cursor for the operating system to boot is over Linux by default.  Therefore, because I don't have a keyboard connected, I can't select to boot OS X.  If I was able to boot OS X, I would be able to connect the wireless keyboard.

Is there any way I can boot OS X without a keyboard?

Thanks.

Comment: What about the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Apple Remote for your Mac, you can try the following:

1. shut down your Mac (by holding the Power button for a few seconds, if necessary)
2. press and hold the Menu button on the Apple Remote
3. start your Mac by pressing the Power button
4. release the Menu button on the Apple Remote

You should now be able to choose a startup volume.

If your keyboard has still not connected to your Mac via Bluetooth, you can select the startup volume by pressing the Left and Right button on the remote. To confirm and boot from the highlighted volume press the Select button.